# AADB2C90083: The request is missing required parameter: grant_type

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to configure the ROPC flow in Azure Active Directory B2C using a custom policy mentioned in the below URL.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/ropc-custom

But I am getting the below error while testing the ROPC policy.
    {
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADB2C90083: The request is missing required 
     parameter: grant_type.\r\nCorrelation ID: b4153dfe-4296-4b68-850f-ee30ac4d86b0\r\nTimestamp: 2019-08-02 11:53:23Z\r\n"
}

Comment: Are you validating ROPC scenario with Native App?

Comment: Try adding grant_type = password

Comment: I have added the grant_type = password but not working.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Have you been able to resolve this? If yes, what was the fix?

Comment: Same bug for me, I have to try again 2 or 3 times and it works

Answer (score 2):

```
https://<your-tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<your-tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=B2C_1A_<POLICY_NAME>&username=xxxxx&password=xxxxx&grant_type=password&scope=openid <NativeClient_App_ID> offline_access&client_id=<NativeClient_App_ID>&response_type=token id_token
```

In the above url add your tenant name, ROPC Signin Policy Name, username & Password and your native client ID.

Now try to send the request and check.

Comment: In the request header, make sure you have the content-type parameter present. `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: This answer worked for me. I used a POST

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error then I realised it should be GET request and I was sending POST. Make sure you are sending correct request type.

Comment: I got the same error trying to [get an access token in authorization flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow#2-get-an-access-token) and this solved it for me too, even though the Docs specify a POST request